# Non-opinion based questions that are confrontational

Tags: discussion, scope

This question has a lot of problems and I would like to ask a question about one of them: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/25015/why-do-evolutionists-label-creationists-as-stupid

I noticed that it was put on hold as "primarily opinion-based".  I am looking for some clarification regarding what exactly is opinion-based.  I could understand closing this question as an attempt to maintain harmony.  The issue of creationalism isn't resolved between "the powers" therefore, we probably won't solve it in this platform.

But just because there are strong differing views on the subject does not mean that it is opinion-based.  For example, if the bible says, "1 + 1 = 3" but I assert that if you have one apple and another apple you have two apples. The question of "What is 1 + 1?" is not opinion based.  I have verifiable experiments showing that when 1 and another 1 come together, there are two.

The OP's question is "why does *x* call *y* stupid" with no references.  The fact that someone considers someone else as one who is lacking intelligence or common sense is an opinion.  But the question itself is not opinion based, no?

Comment: TRiG has answered some of the specifics of the post you mention. For more general principles about what "opinion based" means in the context of this site see my answer the the more generic related question: [How can anything outside of Bible, not be labeled as an opinion?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/3407)

Comment: @Caleb I saw that, that question was asked after mine but they're very similar question.  Thanks for your thorough post.

Comment: The question is not directly about Christianity. It is about what some people say about others, regardless of their affiliation with Christianity.

Comment: I have answered the question Caleb linked to, [spelling out the major types of questions on this site and why they are good](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/3408/3961). Might be helpful to you.

Comment: @TheFreemason I know. But you are asking strangers that believe we came from monkeys and that we came from God at the same time. See Can I believe in evolution and still be a Xtian? What can we do but live life and take it how it comes

Comment: Almost all religion based questions have to be nothing but pure opinion as they can not be proven logically.

Answer (score 7):

- The word *evolutionist* is poorly defined. Does it refer specifically to evolutionary biologists, or to anyone who accepts the evidence for evolution?
- *Do* “evolutionists” think that creationists are stupid? In other words, is the premise of the question correct?
- If “evolutionists” *do* think that creationists are stupid, do they all think this for the same reasons, or do they have a variety of reasons? If there’s a variety of reasons, this question becomes too broad.

Comment: +1 as you are right on as this question is focused on "that" question.  How do you feel about marking questions as "opinion-based" when there are strong differing views which have no hope to be resolved here?  Sometimes "Opinion-based" is used as "I don't want to deal with this"

Comment: @TheFreemason **No**. It is used in the context of this site to mean "we _cannot_ deal with this in this form", usually for questions that fall afoul of the 'truth question' problem. Ironically when something is an opinion question it is often objectively obvious   based on the unusual number of folks who think they have an answer to contribute. For such problem cases **closure is part of the process for dealing with them**. The only thing moderators dread is the flack this generates in comments from people who refuse to understand that this site is about Christianity, not truth.