# Can My Question Be Reopened?

Tags: discussion

I would like to know, if I tell someone that Jesus's physical brain did not contain all knowledge, am I spreading a heresy? Not that someone could *accuse* me of heresy, but that I would be undermining a critical doctrine regarding Jesus. The answer could simply be, "No, there is no established doctrine at this time you would be undermining."

The original question did not, admittedly, articulate my true question.

Here is the link to the question (after edits): https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/35220/does-the-bible-require-jesuss-physical-brain-to-contain-all-knowledge

Comment: Start with this: [Types of questions that are within community guidelines](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3409). Then try to make your question fit into one of those types. It seems like you probably want a Catholic answer. The easiest way to get the post reopened is to specifically say you want a Catholic answer.

Comment: I don't know if you saw my comment, but i did leave it after it was closed. I thought it was answerable by pointing to Mark 13:32 and illustrating it's false premise. Granted, the form of the question likely threw some for a loop, but since the invalidation of the question is readily available, the solution is given.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was closed, because any answer would be just opinion. This site is looking for questions that can be answered *factually* with appropriate supportive citation. Ideally they should be focused to be answerable from an *identifiable specific perspective* within the broad category of Christianity - eg. a denominational or doctrinal perspective. Please refer to [Types of questions that are within community guidelines](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/types-of-questions-that-are-within-community-guidelines) for further information on what is considered an on-topic question in this forum.

Comment: So the problem is that Christianity is too broad of a context? In other words, any answer would be an opinion because some Christians would disagree?

Comment: @user1574787 yes exactly. The post [Christianity.SE vs. Survivor](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/132/christianity-se-vs-survivor) covers some of the relevant issues and is worth checking out.