# Why do questions that the Bible has answers for keep being put on hold?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

I am new to this site. I can answer a lot of these questions that are on hold from the Bible, like the one about the hem of the garment, or what Jesus and Paul said about the Law. These are legitimate questions that the Bible has legitimate answers to.  In fact, I have been answering questions like these from the Bible for almost five years in [my weekly blog](http://comeintothehouseoftruth.blogspot.com/). So why are these questions being put on hold?

Comment: Read [the types of questions that are within community guidelines](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/types-of-questions-that-are-within-community-guidelines). This will help you ask and answer basically the same questions but framing them in such a way so that subjective answers are not included.

Comment: Can you explain why you don't do a little research before you ask a question?  If you look at the down vote arrow, mouse over it, the text says the following: "this question does not show any research effort."  Part of the SE model, over a hundred sites, is *well researched* questions that seek *well supported*, and even *expert*, answers.    If that isn't what you are looking for, or if that isn't something of value to you, then I am not sure how to be of any assistance.   Thanks for the link to your blog, in any event, there's some interesting content there.

Comment: See also: [How can anything outside of Bible, not be labeled as an opinion?](//meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/3407)

Comment: @Caleb After reading all of that, how do you explain this? https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/12383/32750

Comment: I've waited long enough. Apparently there isn't one.

Answer (score 7):

It's because this isn't a site about "what does the Bible say?" but rather about "what do Christians believe?"  That may seem like an insignificant difference, but when you consider the literally thousands of different Christian churches, each with their own way of interpreting many of the same Bible verses, it becomes very significant indeed!

Answer (score 7):

In short, because people disagree about what the Bible says. So rather than asking "What does the Bible say?" we ask "What does the Catholic church think the Bible says about this topic?" or "How do Protestants interpret this passage?"

It may help to think of this site as primarily documenting (through questions and answers) the beliefs and practices of *Christian groups*, not Christianity as a whole, nor the Bible as if there were some single objective interpretation of the Bible.

Please see these other Meta discussions:

- [We can't handle the truth](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3527/6071)
- [Types of questions that are within community guidelines](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3409/6071)

Answer (score 0):

Currently the topics of Christianity.stackexchange are not supposed to be as much about the bible as you might have thought. Topics are limited to Christianity, and its religious teachings. These teachings are some times bible based, but the official church traditions are the reference.

Some of the answers to questions, are using bible quotes, and bible based argumentation, so the idea that you can ask questions about the bible seems logical. But, the answers that you can expect here are about official interpretation of some Christian groups, unless specified with a small disclaimer such as for example “according to the tradition of the Armenian orthodox church or according to the Mormons”. Other answers, even if based on the bible will be removed.

Therefore the scope of this site is really limited to Chistian interpretations, and a lot of bible questions are being put on hold, or even closed. 
So if you ask a question, you should ask what the interpretation of a particular Christian group is on…..? To make it a bit more wide you can add “all perspectives are welcome”, so that at least also non-mainstream interpretations are allowed. A comparison of different Christian interpretations on biblical topics would be also interesting, but unless you phrase it correct, your question is likely to be closed.

If you really wanted to know what is written in the bible about a particular topic. It seems that this website is currently not the right place. Opposite as stated in earlier commends, people do not disagree about what the bible says, (although there are some translation issues), but people disagree about their interpretations of the bible. This website is only about interpretations, and perspectives of Christian groups, with the constraint of avoiding discussion.

Of course it would be possible to allow bible questions, and answers which just contain bible verses and quotations, answering the question asked, with the policy of avoiding discussion. But then that is apparently not the intention of this website. It seems unlikely that the policy will change. Hopefully some body will have the time to set up another stackexchange website about such bible questions. It seems that there is quite a demand for it.

Comment: That website is about exegetical analysis using hermenutics, lets say professional interpretation of bible scriptures. Most questions that are removed or on-hold here, would not be appropriate there to.  People asking those questions seem to be interested in what is written in the bible, and not  in the interpretation, of some Christian Group, or bible scholar. I think a Stack exchange  "Bible Study" could cover many questions, that are not covered by Christianity and Hermeneutics.