# Does my doctrinal stance have to align with anyone to post on here?

Tags: discussion, bible

I've noticed a lot of questions about Catholicism. Is this a catholic 
Website? 
   I don't agree with Catholics or Protestants or Mormons ot Jehovah Witnesses.

If I post views different from the above with many scriptural references, will the posts be deleted?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE, and thanks for taking the site tour. For what's on topic here, please see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This site is primarily about the beliefs of various Christian denominations and the biblical basis for those beliefs, plus other matters of church history, doctrine, and practice that can be answered in a factual manner. Individual opinions don't do so well here, but questions that ask for the biblical basis of a particular belief can, of course, be answered primarily with reference to the Bible.

Comment: @DKing I've been on here consistently for three years and as a Protestant I can say that in that time I've seen absolutely  **no** evidence of Catholic bias in moderation - that's a figment of your imagination. If you have a specific beef about any decision, air it on Meta.

Comment: Yeah, if Jimmy Swaggert ain't your cousin, you don't belong. (just kidding :-)  I suggest that you read many more questions and answers - there are thousands - before you make a half cocked assertion.  Use the search bar.  Pick a few topics if interest to you.  Odds are there are multiple Q&A in an area of interest to you.  In short, no, you are mistaken.

Comment: This needs an update, but it's still very helpful. [Types of on topic questions](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/types-of-questions-that-are-within-community-guidelines). Answers must always fit the question frame.

Answer (score 7):

Allow me to suggest that it's *highly* unlikely that you haven't been influenced by any Christian tradition.  If you take the time to investigate which traditions (Calvinism, Young-Earth Creationism, Pentecostalism, Baptists, Dispensationalism, [Branhamism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_M._Branham), etc.) have views similar to yours on particular subjects, you'll be able to share your own views on a variety of questions by quoting the works of theologians from these traditions.

For example, I'm not a Catholic, but I sometimes answer questions asking for Catholic views, particularly if I happen to share those views (such as [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/44846/21576) and [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/44207/21576)).  But I can't just answer the question by saying "here's what I think"; I have to answer it *using Catholic sources*.

Naturally, if you misrepresent your sources in order to push your own agenda, people will notice and your answers will get downvoted or even deleted.  One of guiding principles of this site is that all traditions associated with Christianity must be treated fairly, and I'd suggest that that includes the people whose writings you quote.

Personally, I have found that taking the time to learn who else shares my views is highly rewarding, because I get to see where my views fit in the grand scheme of things, and I find colleagues where I assumed I had opponents.  It's not easy – not nearly as easy as simply posting what I think.  If that's all you want to do, then you should start your own blog, not post here.

But if you're interested in respectfully interacting with people from other traditions, and exercising self-control to only answer questions that you can answer by citing the views of prominent people from the requested tradition, then you might find this place worthwhile.

Comment: @TheElect et all. Note I have purged the entire comment stream from here. First, this is _meta_, a place to ask questions about and work out how the main site works. It is not a theological debate hall. NONE of the comments here were about the function of the site. This isn't the place to take a stand on some doctrinal point.

Comment: @Caleb *in Monty Python voice* you're no fun anymore. ;)

Answer (score 6):

Taking your questions in order:

> Does my doctrinal stance have to align with anyone to post on here?

A: No, You don't have to adhere to any doctrinal stance to post here, but answers need to correspond to requested viewpoints; and questions that do not specify a viewpoint run the risk of being closed if they aren't objectively answerable.

> I've noticed a lot of questions about Catholicism. Is this a catholic Website?

A: No, but as Catholicism represents one of the most popular (if not the most) identifiable views within Christianity, it is no surprise that there are a lot of Catholic questions on the site.

> If I post views different from the above with many scriptural references, will the posts be deleted?

A: It depends, if the question calls for a particular viewpoint and your answer does not represent that viewpoint, then yes, your posts can be deleted. Not all questions are of this form however, so there may be some questions that you can answer - a typical example may be a question that requests the biblical basis of a particular doctrine.

If you are really only interested in what the Bible says itself rather than how it is interpreted within the context of Christian communities, then perhaps you should consider [the Biblical Hermeneutics site](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/) as being a more appropriate fit for you.

Comment: Not to mention the Catholics have a web friendly and linkable source of "the doctrine/teaching du jour" at the Vatican web site.

Comment: Ok. That was a really good reply. Thanks.

Comment: @TheElect You're welcome. Taking the [tour](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) and browsing the [help centre](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and the [Meta FAQs](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) is probably the best way to quickly get up to speed with how the site operates.

Comment: One more question. Without getting into all the reason for my position , I want to specify my stance on the Canon.  My Bible ends at Luke. I think I should then go to the questions concerning the Canon and jump into those discussions. Does this make sense?

Comment: Ok. I will check out the Hermeneutics site. Thanks

Comment: @TheElect Do you identify as any particular Christian group or movement? Insofar as your beliefs are unique, then they can't really be expressed here. But that is very much allowed at the Hermeneutics site.

Comment: Nope. Just a Disciple of Jesus. He said only He is our teacher. Almost all people walk into a Church, and adopt their traditions. Some are raised in traditions, which they will spend their whole life defending as 'truth'. But the truth is, they are disciples of men, and not Yeshua.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, no. Practically, it may depend on your stance.

This is not a site dedicated to any particular denomination, and since they tend to prefer answer questions, not necessarily about Christianity in general, but regarding doctrinal stances of specific denominations or traditions, your own personal beliefs or even your own denomination's beliefs, shouldn't prevent you from participating.

In my short time here, I have noticed that there is a trend toward questions to, and answers from, Catholic sources. They do generally seem to be preferred, but that may just be speculation.

I think that the current premise of this site favors Catholics in that it is focused to answer questions about denominations from official writings from the denominations. Catholics seem to have the longest tradition of man written, extra-biblical doctrinal stances. There are some other groups, such as LDS or JW, which also have strong traditions of the same, and so it is likewise easier for them to participate, but there seem to be fewer of them who participate, especially of the later. There are many Protestant groups which have long traditions, or at least standard confessions, and so, they do have a somewhat easy time participating.

However, there are those of us who do not have such a written doctrinal stance to reference. I am Independent Fundamental Baptist. We obviously have a history and specific things that we believe, and we do have many authors and publications. Also, in some areas, we're a predominant denomination. Nevertheless, we put a very large emphasis on understanding the Bible and any position taken by any such congregation is considered only as good as the Bible they can give to back it up. There are even groups within the denomination which disagree peacefully on certain stances. The "independent" in the name comes from the fact that we don't believe in having a central authority other than the Bible. IFB seminaries spend maybe a handful of classes which deal with Baptist history and distinctives, and the rest are spent on reading the Bible, learning the core languages, hermaneutics, etc. Since this site prefers to not accept answers from the Bible alone, I still find it hard to participate.

I imagine that if you are non-denominational or perhaps simply somebody who doesn't take a stand on any denomination, that's going to make participation much harder. Such stances are not uncommon, and they are growing. For these groups, you aren't barred from from participating, but you may find fewer opportunities or just have to work harder to join in.

But I'm still new, so there may be some trick I don't know yet, and I'll try to post back here if I learn it.

Comment: I think you are on the right track here.  But consider that even though you are a member of the IFB, you share similarities with larger Christian traditions.  Obviously you're Baptist, and a Protestant – two much bigger groups.  You can probably categorize your views as either particular Baptist (more Reformed) or a general Baptist (more Arminian).  You may be heavily influenced by Dispensationalism (such as if you believe in a pre-tribulation rapture), or not influenced by it.  By learning whose views you share, you can begin to answer questions directed at those traditions on those topics.

Comment: For example, if you are a particular Baptist, you can quote Charles Spurgeon and John Bunyan on a question related to the view of salvation in Reformed theology.  Or, if you're influenced by Dispensationalism, you can quote the Moody Bible Commentary or the Ryrie Study Bible on questions about the end times.  I have found it very fruitful to learn which other traditions share my views on particular subjects – it helps me see that I am not a lone ranger Christian, and that many other traditions, though disagreeing with me on important matters, still honestly seek to know God.

Comment: *I think that the current premise of this site favors Catholics in that it is focused to answer questions about denominations from official writings from the denominations*  You might want to read more of the back catalogue.