# Proposed addition to "How to Ask" block

Tags: discussion, feature-request, scope

One of the most difficult challenges I had when first participating with this site was overcoming the urge to be part of a conversation.  It took a long time to understand (and a part of me will likely never completely agree with it) that the site's very structure makes discussion-based answers (e.g., "what does everybody think about X?") difficult to manage.  They certainly don't fit within the one-question-one-correct-answer format Stack Exchange has created.

Therefore, I propose we add verbiage similar to the following to the "[How to Ask](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)" block that appears when people ask a new question.  It's purpose would be to decrease the liklihood that a question will be closed, which can result in new partipants not coming back.

> Address your question to specific Christian denominations or traditions.

---

**EDIT:** @fredsbend makes a good point about not wanting to limit or exclude questions just because they don't need to reference a particular group.  Therefore, let me present alternative #1:

> When asking about scriptural or dogmatic beliefs, it is best to address your question to specific Christian denominations or traditions.

Comment: But that's not the only way you can ask. https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/types-of-questions-that-are-within-community-guidelines

Comment: That was an insightful post, but I suspect a review of questions would demonstrate the vast majority of questions posited by new users and closed would be perfectly good if focused on a specific Christian group.  The proposed statement can be clarified to account for your great post by making it longer, but longer isn't always better.  Is there an alternative that would help new posters?

Comment: I'm not saying it wouldn't help, but it gives an incomplete impression of what the site is about.

Comment: I can support the alternative #1