# Is it politically correct to ban a user from Jesus.SE?

Tags: discussion, political-correctness, banning

I'm having issue with this more than other SE sites I visit because I feel there should be no limit on Questions about Jesus as long as they are new.

Should users who ask to many low quality questions, showing a true interest in Jesus be suspended or banned from asking? Could a more lenient policy or the system parameters be changed to be more forgiving to a sincere user?

[Did Jesus ever get Married?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/67697/did-jesus-ever-get-married)

Update: Well I tried to ask a good question and failed to get off the indefinite  question ban. I'll try to reflect and ask a better question in 6 months. Boooooo

Comment: The best way to clear an automatic question ban is to edit your existing content to make it more readable, more useful, and more on-topic, so that it gets undeleted, reopened, and/or voted up.

Comment: @Nathaniel I will try but my questions can be really hard to fix for they are just bad. It is really hard to lift a question bad when you have the same old users always down voting your retribution question regardless of quality.

Comment: Make sure that you have read [Types of questions that are within community guidelines](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3409/6071), and if you think you are at risk of getting an automatic question ban, make sure you only ask questions that are firmly within the community standards.

Comment: Why are you calling it Jesus SE? My first feeling when I see that is skepticism in your earnestness.

Answer (score 7):

People are not being banned by moderators unless they're violate [the Big Laws](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct).  We don't control the triggers for automatic   *Latae sententiae* banning.  So we'd have to take it up with corporate to institute a "Be Nicer" policy.  If you want to write an essay here in favor of that, please go ahead - but I think you'd have to make a very good case.

What exactly do people lose by having to wait a bit before asking another question?  IMO they gain time to reflect on what they're asking. So it's a should be better for the site and the person for there to be perfunctory banning.

Comment: I don't need 6 months to reflect. Unless egregious a month tops for a bad question. Do you want me to write a proposal on this for the SE Team for this site?

Answer (score 6):

Should this SE be more forgiving?  No.  Regardless of the topic (Christianity, Physics, whatever), if a person has a history of asking low quality questions, then a ban is appropriate.

In order to get to the point that they're question banned, someone has to have asked a number of badly-received questions and been unable or unwilling to fix them.  Even then, there's the "faint hope" option of asking one question every 6 months to try to do better.

In your case, you're active on multiple SE sites but have been banned on several of them. 
Despite receiving lots of feedback, you are *not* showing "improvement and a will to learn" - you still tend to ask unclear or badly defined questions.  I'm sorry to say it, but you are an example of why SE shouldn't be more lenient: despite receiving lots of help over a long period of time, your questions and answers have not improved much so you deserve to be banned.

Comment: That is not for you to say. I am learning and want to do better. I am sorry I am not the best at writing or being on topic. I am not trying to cause trouble. I enjoy this site and the system is not fair to people with lots of questions to ask.

Comment: Just as an example of how you _aren't_ learning: I didn't notice the tags you put on your post until just now.  After being active on SE for as long as you've been, you really should know what tags are for, and after being as active on various metas as much as you have, you should know what tags are for here.  Instead, you've slapped "bug" and "political correctness" tags on your post, which make no sense.

Comment: Updated question. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure about this site, but I've seen people on other SE sites tell you that you aren't supposed to radically change your question in a way that invalidates existing answers, but that's exactly what you've done here, and you've pretty much done it to your "was Jesus a virgin?" question as well.  If you keep doing things after people explain why you shouldn't do them, that's not learning.