# Can a question be BOTH off and on topic?

Tags: discussion

In this question: [What are the requirements to be a prophet?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/71919/what-are-the-requirements-to-be-a-prophet) Peter Turner asks "A current day prophet or a old testament prophet?" and I said both. Then which his reply was to close the question. I am guessing one is off topic while the other is on topic. In my mind they are one in the same.

Can some one explain to me how one is off topic while the other is on topic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No a question can't be both on and off-topic at the same time. Though for some edge cases the community may disagree about whether a particular question is off-topic.

I won't try to speak to Peter's actions here.

Instead I want to ask you why you still refuse to learn and abide by this site's rules. You have had multiple question bans. That is remarkable in a way!

Here's your number one tip: do not ask another question that is not [precisely one of these question types](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3409/6071).