# What are some good questions for me to ask on here?

Tags: discussion

I remember asking a question on here on this website, and was told that this wasn’t actually a forum and such, I would like to ask how can I ask a good question on here?

Comment: Please take the [site tour](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) and review some highly voted questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Types of questions that are within community guidelines](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/types-of-questions-that-are-within-community-guidelines)