# Was the circumcision question put on hold for valid reason?

Tags: discussion, truth-questions

This question https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/50629/why-did-god-gave-circumcision-to-abraham

Was put on hold called a truth question. I think it is a question answerable from scripture with no need to interject opinion.

I am wondering if others agree that it should Not be on hold.

Or suggest how it could be edited to fit the rules if you agree with the action taken by those who put it on hold.

Thanks in advance I know I am certainley not fully up to speed on how this stuff works but sometimes it seems too many questions are closed.

Comment: I am inclined to agree the question is a simple scriptural question IMO.

Comment: Drive by down votes are  so uncool  like flipping the bird at a tourist who is trying to change lanes in a strange town

Comment: No @Kris it's not like that at all. Downoting on meta is not like flipping the bird, it's an expression of disagreement with a proposal or question.  You're question was "I am wondering if others agree" and so far you should read the votes as "1 person agrees, 3 people disagree". End of story. This is true even if the votes _were_ "drive by" as you call them, but they are not: so far two people have taken the time to respond in detail and other voters have expressed their agreement with those explanations.

Answer (score 6):

> I think it is a question answerable from scripture with no need to interject opinion.

This is a common misunderstanding, but answering *anything* from scripture requires interpretation and some degree of application. Whether *you* see this as interjecting opinion or not, the interpretive framework you use will come across in the result and an answer from somebody with a fundamentally different framework will necessarily be different. Given that there are groups using the label "Christian" that don't even believe the text of the Bible is God's inspired word, just "Biblical answers" is not a sufficient scope for questions on this site.

I elaborated on this idea in some detal [in a previous post](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3407/30). You might find it helpful to review that and other meta posts regarding the issue with "truth" questions on this site.

Comment: Okay the op states. "I'm asking the question in perspective of Abraham and the children of Israel." That narrows it to a degree that should keep answers from going into anti typical figurative circumcision answers that are opionion based and vary by denomination. Do you have a suggestion on editing this question to make it a fit for CSE?

Answer (score 5):

When it comes to questions of "why", there is essentially no such thing as a purely objective scriptural question because Scripture can be and is interpreted in an extremely wide variety of ways. Trying to discern the mind of God just exacerbates the problem. Thus, in its current form, the question should remain on hold.

Consider the posted close reason (emphasis mine):

> Questions asking for the truth or validity of a particular doctrine or belief (aka Truth Questions), and questions asking Is X a Sin? are not a good fit for our site, due to their subjective nature, and **the vast number of possible Christian opinions on such topics**. See: [We can't handle the truth](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3527/20)

There were three answers by the time it was put on hold, all with vastly differing opinions expressed. There is no one objective answer to the question as it currently stands.